# How to get a shell variable in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

in my Makefile, i want to get the read function return value. but it doesn't work

```
all: 
    git add .
    git commit -m $(shell read -r -p "please write some message: ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to ask for input inside a makefile.  Makefiles are intended to be non-interactive.  You could instead require users to set a make variable with the message, like `make all MSG='here is some message'` and fail if it wasn't set.

However, if you really do want to do this interactively you have a number of problems.

First, make's `shell` function expands to the value that the shell prints to stdout, and the shell's `read` built-in doesn't write output to stdout; it stores that output in the `$REPLY` variable (or a different variable you provide.  So if you wanted this to work it would have to be something like:

```
all:
        git add .
        git commit -m "$(shell read -r -p "please write some message: "; printf '%s\n' $$REPLY)"
```

But, it's almost always a mistake to use make's `shell` function inside a recipe: a recipe already runs in the shell, so trying to use make's `shell` function just adds confusion for no additional benefit.

Try:

```
all:
        git add .
        read -r -p "please write some message: "; git commit -m "$$REPLY"
```

Comment: If you invoke `git commit` without the `-m`, it prompts for a commit message in the editor — which is probably better because it allows for message formatting etc.  But any interaction in a makefile is a pain in the posterior.  I tend towards the view that if the makefile cannot create a suitable message automatically, it should not be doing the commit anyway.

Comment: The problem with starting an editor is the same one as using `read` but even moreso: it's not guaranteed that any program you invoke in a make recipe will be attached to the normal stdin / stdout of your terminal.  This is especially true if you try to run make with parallelism (`-j`) because obviously only one parallel job can have access to stdin.